# How to calculate quantized angle?

Tags: image-processing

I am looking at the code for Hough transformation in image segmentation. The following code is from Computer Vision by Linda Shapiro. Can somebody tell me what is `quantize_angle` and how can I compute it?

[image: code for Hough transformation in image segmentation from Computer Vision by Linda Shapiro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hough transform looks for straight lines (or other features) in an image and represents these features as points in a different 2D coordinate system, where one axis represents the angle *θ* of a detected line, and the other represents the distance *δ* from this line to the centre of the image.

[image: Hough transform illustration from Wikipedia]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hough-example-result-en.png)</sup>

To produce a Hough transform of finite dimensions, both *θ* and *δ* have to be quantized. For example, if *θ* lies in the range (0 ≤ *θ* < 2π), then you could map it to the range 0–255 by a function such as the following:

```
int quantize_angle(float theta) {
    int q = floor(theta * 128.0 / 3.141592654 + 0.5);
    return q % 256;
}
```

This will result in a Hough transform that is 256 pixels wide.

Comment: Note that the `cos` and `sin` functions take a quantized angle, not an angle in radians.

Comment: Thanks, Is the value 128 only for 256 pixels or it is a general formula?

Comment: @Fred Just for 256 pixels. In general: `q = floor(TRANSFORM_WIDTH * theta / (2 * PI) + 0.5);`